# foreach / dofuture throwing error on rstudio server only

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rstudio-server

I have R code that I run in parallel like so:

```
library(foreach)
library(doFuture)

registerDoFuture()
plan(multicore, workers=12)

result <- foreach(i=1:N, .combine=c) %dopar% {
        myfunction(mydata[[i]])
    }
```

Here's what happens:

- On my machine, sequentially: no error
- On my machine, in parallel:  no error
- On my school's RStudio server, sequentially: no error
- On my school's RStudio server, in parallel:  the following error

> Error in vapply(where, FUN = envname, FUN.VALUE = NA_character_,
>   USE.NAMES = FALSE) :    values must be length 1,  but FUN(X[[5]])
>   result is length 0

Literally the same code with the same data. And in the past I have been able to run code in parallel on the school's RStudio server. Any idea as to what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Does it work with fewer workers? Perhaps the admins put resource limits in-place?

Comment: Unfortunately the error persists even when using just 2 workers.

Comment: I've noticed that I also get the same error message anytime I "re-assign" the number of workers that I want within an RStudio server session -- I'm not sure if this is related, but maybe worth mentioning...

Comment: You're using `future` as well, aren't you? I don't see where else `plan` is exported.

Comment: Could you try testing `doParallel` instead of `doFuture`? Just to check if it's backend-specific.

Comment: Author of the future framework here.  My suggestions for troubleshooting this discrepancy is to compare versions of R, versions of packages (`sessionInfo()` etc) and versions of RStudio involved.  Hard to give more help without a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Thank you all for the help.  The error does not occur with `doParallel` and continues to persist with `doFuture` leading me to believe it is backend-specific, as suggested by @Alexis.